# How to use XCTest framework to test REST based native iOS appliction?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

Tried to check out how to use XCTest framework for an application which is using REST web services. But did not find any good and complete example tutorial.

I have only some basic idea of XCTest but confused to use XCTest with REST application.

Can anybody give me some examples of how to use this. I just need the idea and direction and then I can go.

**Note:** If the application is a basic application, I know but my confusion is only for REST based iOS application testing.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `XCTestExpectation` for testing client-server communication that is based on REST protocol.
Here is high level example:

```
- (void)testCreatingUserRequest {
    // Initialize necessary objects
    RestManager *restManager = ...
    CreatingUserRequest *request = ...

    // Execute test
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Create User"];

    [restManager createUserWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *JSONObject, NSError *error) {
        XCTAssertNotNil(JSONObject);
        XCTAssertNotNil([User userWithJSONObject:JSONObject]);
        XCTAssertNil(error);

        [expectation fulfill];
    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:30 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        XCTAssertNil(error);
    }];
}
```

This test cover such expectation cases:
 1. Server has to return response in 30 seconds or less;
 2. Server has to return valid JSON object with valid response code;
 3. JSON object has to have correct structure for mapping to User object.